# How to run a PowerShell script for all user accounts on a computer?

Tags: powershell

I have a simple PS script to remove network printers from the logged on account. I would like to be able to run it against all user profiles on the computer. Is this possible other than putting the script in the startup folder?

Here's the script:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_Printer | where{$_.Network -eq 'true'} | foreach{$_.delete()}
```

Comment: Are you looking to remove network printers from logged off users as well? The users registry hives, where these mappings are stored, would be unloaded and not accessible by these means. GPO or start up would be cleaner I think.

Comment: Yes, for all potential user accounts on that computer (and others eventually).

Comment: Seconding Matt, I would use GPO to run this script.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scheduled task that's scheduled for user log in. You can create this scheduled task via Group Policy Preferences.

You can also use Group Policy to push out a login script.